# I have problem to render data after API fetch because I have two apis and the second api call depend on first api ID

Tags: reactjs, typescript, fetch-api

App.tsx

```
export interface Hotel {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  address1: string;
  address2: string;
  starRating: number;
  images: string[];
  longDescription: string;
}

// currently not using types but may be it should be like that
export interface Hotel {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    address1: string;
    address2: string;
    starRating: number;
    images: string[];
    longDescription: string;
    room: {
        id: string;
        name: string;
        longDescription: string;
        occupancy: {
            maxAdults: number;
            maxChildren: number;
            maxOverall: number;
        };
    };
}

//

export interface Room {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  longDescription: string;
}

const App: React.FC = () => {
    // const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const [hotels, setHotels] = useState<Hotel[]>([]);
    const [rooms, setRooms] = useState<Room[]>([]);

useEffect(() => {
        const getData = async () => {
            const { data: hotels } = await axios.get<Hotel[]>(
                'https://obmng.dbm.guestline.net/api/hotels?collection-id=OBMNG'
            );
            const allRooms = await Promise.all(
                hotels.map(async ({ id }) => {
                    // don't forget to provide a type for the response
                    const {
                        data: { rooms },
                    } = await axios.get<{ rooms: Room[] }>(
                        `https://obmng.dbm.guestline.net/api/roomRates/OBMNG/${id}`
                    );

                    return rooms;
                })
            );

            console.log(hotels);
            console.log(allRooms.flat());

            setHotels(hotels);
            setRooms(allRooms.flat());
        };
        getData();
    }, []);

return (
        <div>
            <GlobalStyle />
            <ImageWrapper>
                <BrandTitle>Book Your Stay</BrandTitle>
                <BrandSubtitle>make yourself comfortable with us</BrandSubtitle>
            </ImageWrapper>
            <HotelCard hotels={hotels} rooms={rooms} />-
        </div>
    );
};
```

HotelCard.tsx

```
interface HotelListProps {
  hotels: Hotel[];
  rooms: Room[];
}

const HotelCard: React.FC<HotelListProps> = ({ hotels, rooms }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {hotels.map((hotel) => (
        <div key={hotel.id}>
          <h1>{hotel.id}</h1>
          // more code
        </div>
      ))}
      {rooms.map((room) => (
        <div key={room.id}>
          <h1>{room.name}</h1>
          // more here...
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default HotelCard;
```

In this code I get result like all hotels from first api and then I use id which I got from first api call and use that one in second api request. I stored both api response in different state(hotels, rooms). but i got different result in screen. I need to render like, first hotel1 then 3 rooms of hotel1 then again hotel2 and 3 rooms of hotel2 and rest of them same, but rightnow I got first hotel then all rooms together. how to achieve that? I am really confuse about that could anyone help me? I will really thankful for that?

Comment: You might want to look into the "dependent queries" feature of the `react-query` library

Answer (score 0):

First organize your data into the structure you want

```
const joined = hotels.map(h => {
  hotel: h,
  rooms: rooms.filter(r => r.hotelId === h.id), // Or however your docs are linked
});

// Then

joined.map(j => <>
  <h1>{j.hotel.id}</h1>
  {j.rooms.slice(0, 2).map(r => <h1>{r.id}</h1>)}
  </>);
```